# Error in creating role

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

> Class Vanguard\Http\Controllers\Web\ RolesController does not exist

the error show like this.

Then it says like this. Please see picture attached for reference. [Error that shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u584u.png)

Comment: This question can be closed as 'typographical error'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see, there is a space before `RolesController`?

Replace

```
Vanguard\Http\Controllers\Web\ RolesController
```

with

```
Vanguard\Http\Controllers\Web\RolesController
                              ^-- Remove the space
```

Comment: Where is that part? @Saiyan Prince

Comment: Thank you @saiyan prince